# How can I create a pdf in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf-generation

anyone who can help me create a pdf in android. I want a scenario where I can pass data to the pdf, view it, and be able to download it to my phone.

Best Regards

Comment: https://gonehybrid.com/how-to-create-and-display-a-pdf-file-in-your-ionic-app/

Comment: @HarshaW Thanks. Let me check

Comment: I like the open source one from Firefox: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: @pixelbits checking it